# Why does "ExcludeControlFromAero" doesn't work?

Tags: c#, .net, aero, aero-glass

I'm using the [Microsoft Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) to display a form as "GlassForm". In that GlassForm I need to exclude my combobox from Aero, because the font of it is also getting transparent, but

```
this.ExcludeControlFromAeroGlass(comboBox);
```

doesn't work for me. Even if i Invalidate the form after.

Also the form isn't 'Aero' if I publish the app over the build in function of Visual Studio 2013

Comment: with publishing i mean publishing it to a webspace (ClickOnce Application)

Comment: Same issue here. Anything black goes glass by default. Setting a different transparency key doesn't work, because if one is set at all, the form becomes click-through (windows underneath glass areas will receive events), so we're stuck with keeping window (form) transparency key NULL (unset) and the default "black becomes glass" behavior. The real problem is that the built-in controls ComboBox, TextBox, ListView, etc. do not have a "UseCompatibleTextRendering" option, so instead of using GDI+, they all use GDI with no transparency. Setting a non-black text color is also not helpful.